# Deploy React in XAMPP

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React, and try to deploy app in my local machine using XAMPP. My problem is, when i tried to access the webpage, its gives 404 Not Found. When using `npm start`, its working properly.

[image]

I tried some advice from other similar question, but its still not working. This is my index.js

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter basename='/react'>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

And I put   `"homepage": "http://localhost/react/"` in `package.json`

```
  "homepage": "http://localhost/react/",
  "name": "admin-dashboard-presensi",
```

After that, I run `npm run build` and move the folder to htdocs/react

[image]

This is what I put inside `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What is in your npm start? By right when you run npm start, it should show you the port number in the terminal, so your url should be `http://localhost:portnumber`

Comment: Yeah its working properly when using npm start, and its running on port 3000. But I want to deploy it on XAMPP instead of using `npm start`

Comment: Move the **contents** of the `build` folder into `htdocs/react`, not the `build` folder itself

Comment: @Phil I see, thank you very much. Its working now.

Answer (score -1):

Possible Error Sincaio:

1- You add url to package.json before you are build

2- missing to restart XAMPP server

3- make sure the folder build name is react, else rename directory or change base `<BrowserRouter basename='/react'>` and rebuild

4- also check the directory full path is correct, and its has permission which its allow you to visit it.

> More Details: (Move the contents of the build folder into
> htdocs/react, not the build folder itself => Copied from @Phil)

If above points not work, you can check details bellow:
I think you missing hosts and/or virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerName my-website.local
    ServerAlias www.my-website.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@my-website.local
    DocumentRoot "path/to/your/build"
     <Directory path/to/your/build>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you need to add your new domain to hosts:
vim `/etc/hosts` and add:

```
127.0.0.1 my-website.local
```

### Another details may help you if its missing in your setup

Also, you need to make sure you are put .htaccess in **public directory** before build:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

and then add: `"homepage": "http://www.my-website.local"`, to `package.json`

Rebuild again, and restart XAMPP.

Note: I add alias domain nested of normal localhost, its better, but you can ignore that.

Comment: Base on my answer, point number 4 is resolve issue for Ananda (base on comments discuses)!